# Как получить данные из другого приложения?

Tags: c++, hook

Есть десктопное приложение, нашел нужною dll
[image: Данные которые нужно прочитать]

Нужно получить доступ к этим поля из с++(в дальнейшем подключу к WPF приложению).
Остановился на этапе доступа к данным из данной dll. Вопрос в том как получить данные из DrawTextW.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под `как получить данные из DrawTextW`? Какие данные? Хотите поставить хук для извлечения переданных данных в функцию? Или вы хотите перехватить полностью вызов данной функции?

Comment: Конкретно, мне нужно эти *30.23* получить на выходе, данные.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю вам подойдет такое решение [subhook](https://github.com/Zeex/subhook).

В использовании можете написать вот такой код, а так же исправить и улучшить его на свой вкус:

```
subhook_t DrawTextW_hook;

LONG DrawTextWHooked(HDC hdc, LPCTSTR lpchText, int lpchText,
                     LPRECT lprc, UINT lprc)
{
    // Удалить хук, чо бы вызвать оригинальную функцию
    subhook_remove(DrawTextW_hook);

    printf("%s called\n", __func__);

    // Тут вы можете работать со всем параметрами переданными в `DrawTextW`

    // Вызов оригинальной функции
    LONG reuslt = DrawTextW(hdc, lpchText, lpchText, lprc, lprc);

    // Установить обратно хук, что бы последуующие вызовы, попадали сюда.
    subhook_install(DrawTextW_hook);

    // Вернуть результат
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    DrawTextW_hook = subhook_new((void*)DrawTextW,
                                 (void*)DrawTextWHooked, (subhook_options)0);

    subhook_install(DrawTextW_hook);


    // Ваш код... И так далее, не обязательно тут, а там где вам необходимо

    // Перед выходом, удалите хук, и освободите ресурсы выделенные под хук

    subhook_remove(DrawTextW_hook);
    subhook_free(DrawTextW_hook);
}
```